# Extracting arguments using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use regex to extract the arguments from a function definition into an array. For example

```
func(a) -> ['a']
func(a,b) -> ['a','b']
func(a, b) -> ['a','b']
```

The regex below correctly matches the arguments block

```
/\((?:(\w+),?\s*)+\)/
```

However, only the last matched capturing group is returned i.e. the results are:

```
func(a) -> ['a']
func(a,b) -> ['b']
func(a,b,c) -> ['c']
```

This seems like it would be a generally useful pattern for capturing part of a repeating unit. Is there any way to correctly achieve the expected result?

My saved regexr session can be found [here](http://regexr.com/3bg8u/)

Comment: What language? Does the language have a reflection API? Why don't you include the `func` part in the regex?

Comment: There are 2 indications of JS: 1) regexr and 2) the regex used.

Comment: the reason it is not capturing whole pattern is because you are using `(?:)` which is called non capturing group, and why go into that much trouble when this can be done with `(?<=\()(.*)(?=\))` or even `(\((.*)\))`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the arguments like this:

```js
var s = "func(a, b,  c )";
var res = s.substring(s.indexOf("(") + 1, s.indexOf(")")).split(/\s*,\s*/g);
alert(res);
```

This will work if you have independent strings like those in your sample input.

And another way I was trying to add is extract the parenthetical group with `/\(([^()]+)\)/` regex and then split the captured group 1 contents with `.split(/\s*,\s*/g)`.

Comment: Javascript was not a tag in this post, and OP asked for a regex solution.

Comment: Oh, surely it can easily be done with \G. I lost my primary Internet connection, I will post as soon as I get normal access again.However, regexr is working for JS regexps, AFAIK, not PHP or Ruby.

Comment: @blindoverhang: Oh, I see the tag is added, so my current solution seems optimal. Anyway, a solution with \G looks like [`(?:\(|(?!^)\G)\K\s*([^,\s]+)\s*,?\s*(?=[^()]*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/lE2oI8/1) but is only good for PCRE/Oniguruma/.NET 4.5 regex flavors.

Answer (score 0):

The regex `/\((\w+(?:,\s?\w+)?)\)/` will return `a, b` for `func(a, b)`, as well as `a,b,c` for `func(a,b,c)`

Hopefully this is what you wanted, depending on what language you're doing this for, you can simply split them by each `,` to put them into an array for indexing later.